# Importing functions from files located in a different directory when working with different computers without the need of changing the path

Tags: python, pytest

I have developed a small program file_1.py and am now developing its test file_2.py. They are in different folders. To do the test, I want to import the functions from file_1 to file_2. To import the functions from files located in differents folders I have seen this approach:

```
# file_2.py
import sys
sys.path.append('/.../application/app/folder')
from file_1 import *
```

```
application
 ├── app
 │   └── folder
 │       └── file_1.py
 └── app2
     └── some_folder
         └── file_2.py
```

The program is to be used by clients in different computers and I want to write the code of the file_2.py in a way that they can run the test just by writing `python file_2.py`

How can I do this without the need of modifying the path in every different computer? All machines are Mac or Linux.

Update:

This is a copy of the real code I am using:

```
from VCF_matcher.app.run import * 


NAME_FILE_1 = "./test_sample.vcf"

# FIRST TEST

def test_load_sample():
    data = load_sample (NAME_FILE_1)
    assert len(data) == 10425
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do in `file2.py`:

```
from app.folder.file_1 import *
```

Comment: As simple as this? Thanks, I was expecting a much more complicated way to do this. I will try this and I will come back later in a second commend to tell you if this works

Comment: I have added the code I am using in which you will see your suggestion. With this, I have got this error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'VCF_matcher'

Comment: @JorgeAlbertoPalacios
create a dunder init file ```__init__.py``` under that folder (It will make it a py package)

Comment: you mean to write ``` __init__.py  ``` at the end of the file file_1 ??

Comment: @JorgeAlbertoPalacios
No, create a ```__init__.py``` file under VCF_matcher
see: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-access-python-package/

Comment: Yes thank you. I have needed to add this empty file in the VCF_matcher, app and testing folders if I want to import the function from the file file_2. I don't know if that is correct but it seems that is working know